# angularjs not updating partial on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs

I'm having a weird problem and I don't know where to start. Consider the following flow:

1) User gets on Waiting page (controller + partial) with param1. param1 sets a $scope.sectionTitle and works great.

2) The Waiting page redirects to a processing page which redirects back to the waiting page with param2 that sets $scope.sectionTitle again.

At the second step the HTML shows the raw {{sectionTitle}} instead of value that was set in the controller.

This only happens on my testing on iOS. It seems to work ok on the desktop.

Where can I start to debug this? What could be happening?

Comment: It could be lots of things. how are you redirecting between the pages? Do you have a link to somewhere this could be tested?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, the partial is fetched from a URL, could there be some caching going on? On the first request, you get the real view, on the second one, the iOS browser takes some shortcut, which prevents Angular.js from properly rendering the view.

Does it work if you add some random parameter to the URL?

Comment: Doesn't work with a random parameter. In fact it doesn't get the partial again.

Answer (score 0):

If I add $scope.$apply() it works. Digest is borked for some reason on iOS.